# How do I calculate permutations where order matters and sets are different lengths?

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations, permutation, factorial

Let's say I have 3 sets of characters:
    ["1"],["a","b"],["C",D","E"]

and the length of the permutation is 3. Ex: 1aC

Position 1: Will always be "1"
Position 2: Will always be "a" OR "b"
Position 3: Will always be "C" OR "D" OR "E"

How would I calculate the total number of permutation possible?

I have looked through many pages on permutations but can't seem to find one describing this scenario, they all seem to assume the sets are the same length or all use the same set.

Comment: What you're describing is the "Cartesian product" of the sets. See Cardinality of Cartesian Product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cardinality

Answer (score 2):

It's simply the product of the sizes of the sets, so `1*2*3` in this case. This is the basic general principle: every other formula in this topic is derived from this.

Comment: Naturally I couldn't find information on it since it's so simple. Doh. Thanks for the help, I thought this was correct, but my code didn't output the correct number. Probably have an off-by-one error.